# Time Complexity - Reducing Square Matrix to Diagonal Matrix (using Gaussian Row Elimination)

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

**Given:** A Square Matrix where each entry is an integer (either positive or negative). The magnitude of each integer entry is at most $m$ bits. The size of the Square matrix is $nXn$.

**Objective:** Reduce the Square Matrix to a Diagonal Matrix form using Gaussian Row Elimination.

**Query:** What is the most efficient algorithm and its time complexity for the above?

Comment: Most sources discuss the number of operations but not the total computational complexity. The obvious method is to use the text book method of row elimination. But i am assuming in the worst case, it is possible for the intermediate matrix entries to blow up exponentially in their size (w.r.t. to $m$). Thus, i am not clear.

Can someone help with the most efficient algorithm to achieve the above and its time complexity? (a clear reference to a textbook/source where that algorithm as well as its complexity is derived would be equally great).

P.S. I was suggested this link [1](https://disopt.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/disopt/files/shared/IntPoints2009/basic-algorithms.pdf) but it is not very clear (either Algorithm or its complexity)

Comment: Anyone please? I don't think there is anything wrong with the Query..

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2820546/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.